# Why does pandas return timestamps instead of datetime objects when calling pd.to_datetime()?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timestamp

According to the [manual](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.tseries.tools.to_datetime.html), `pd.to_datetime()` should create a datetime object.

Instead, when I call `pd.to_datetime("2012-05-14")`, I get a timestamp object! Calling `to_datetime()` on that object finally gives me a datetime object.

```
In [1]: pd.to_datetime("2012-05-14")
Out[1]: Timestamp('2012-05-14 00:00:00', tz=None)

In [2]: t = pd.to_datetime("2012-05-14")
In [3]: t.to_datime()
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 14, 0, 0)
```

Is there an explanation for this unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A `Timestamp` object is the way pandas works with datetimes, so it *is* a datetime object in pandas. But you expected a `datetime.datetime` object.
Normally you should not care about this (it is just a matter of a different repr). As long as you are working with pandas, the Timestamp is OK. And even if you really want a `datetime.datetime`, most things will work (eg all methods), and otherwise you can use `to_pydatetime` to retrieve the `datetime.datetime` object.

The longer story:

- pandas stores datetimes as data with type `datetime64` in index/columns (this are not `datetime.datetime` objects). This is the standard numpy type for datetimes and is more performant than using `datetime.datetime` objects:

  ```
   In [15]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[dt.datetime(2012,1,1), dt.datetime(2012,1,2)]})

   In [16]: df.dtypes
   Out[16]:
   A    datetime64[ns]
   dtype: object

   In [17]: df.loc[0,'A']
   Out[17]: Timestamp('2012-01-01 00:00:00', tz=None)
  ```
- when retrieving one value of such a datetime column/index, you will see a `Timestamp` object. This is a more convenient object to work with the datetimes (more methods, better representation, etc than the datetime64), and this is a subclass of `datetime.datetime`, and so has all methods of it.